# Sync form data from localStorage to online database in angularjs

Tags: php, android, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to make an app for Android using angularjs and Phonegap and  I have already used ngStorage to store data in localStorage. If there is no internet connectivity now I want to store data from  form data in localStorage and when internet connection is back then the stored data will automatically  sync with online database.Like as "WhatsApp".My need to consultation it's possible or not. Anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you share some code that shows what you tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I already save data  localStorage when available online but i want to offline data localstorage save  and check internet when get internet then automatically data pickup from localstorage to online database.